# libGDX fileHandle cannot readString()

Tags: java, libgdx

I have created a text file called "useraccounts.txt". All I want to do is to read the file using the filehandle class but I always get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Cannot open a stream to a directory: useraccounts.txt (Local)
```

Here is my code:

```
FileHande accountsFile = Gdx.files.local("useraccounts.txt");
String text = accountsFile.readString();
```

Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an `internal` handle (`Gdx.file.internal`)? 
What does the internal exception of the RuntimeException say?

Comment: I'm using local because I need write access. Using the internal handle, I am having the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration, I found out that I had made a folder the same name with the text file by mistake!! After deleting the folder all works fine, thank you for replying!

Comment: Then please mark your own answer as the correct one, to close this question.

Comment: I have to wait for a day

Comment: Okay, now then.